# IBM Worklight 6.0 - What environments are there Worklight Settings page available?

Tags: android, ios, windows, settings, ibm-mobilefirst

Using Worklight to build an Android app, you can easily find the Worklight Settings page thru the menu button on Android.

In what other environments are this page (Worklight Settings) available ? And how to get to this page ? For those not available what are the alternatives ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Worklight Settings is currently available for the Android and iOS environments.

When enabled, you can reach it:

- In Android: by tapping on the Menu button
- In iOS: by navigating to Settings.app > scroll all the way down to find your app

For other environments, if your app uses the multiple pages approach, you could simply create a dedicate HTML for this and navigate to it from the app's UI (and design it as you please).

**NOTE**: the Worklight Settings feature is NOT meant for production / end-user usage; it is for development time or for very specific use cases, probably in internal apps in your company. You cannot add options to the Worklight Settings feature provided by Worklight.

Comment: considering I go with my custom page (for WP8), is there any API call to change WL server IP Address in the same way the native WL settings page does currently ?